# Non-void function returns nothing dart

Tags: function, dart, return-value, return-type

I have a function that returns int value but in some circumstances I want to terminate the function and return nothing.

Just to show an example:

```
int numberFunc(int num){
    if(num > 10){
       return; 
/* terminates the function for numbers more than 10 */
     }
    return num;
}
```

This works fine but I get a warning that says the function has a return type of int but it doesn’t finish with a return statement.

Will there be a problem if I use something like this and what can be a solution for that?

Thanks

**Solution:**

As julemand101 explained, We can return a null value. Also the code above returns a null value for numbers more than 10 so we have to take care of the possible null values later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you properly want is to return `null` to indicate that the method are not returning any value:

```
int numberFunc(int num){
    if(num > 10){
       return null; 
/* terminates the function for numbers more than 10 */
     }
    return num;
}
```

But remember that the method which are using the result from numberFunc needs to be aware that the returned value can be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just return **null**. It's a default value for any type that has not been set yet.

Ex.:

**int i;** is the same as **int i = null**

Comment: Quick question, if I have int x = numberFunc(20); with the same code I wrote, wouldn’t be the result a null value?

Comment: Yes, so you need to make sure you code works even if `x` are `null`. E.g. test if the value returned are `null` with `if (x == null)`.

Comment: There are also null aware operators you can use: https://medium.com/@thinkdigitalsoftware/null-aware-operators-in-dart-53ffb8ae80bb