# Why do some If statements have "return" without any value?

Tags: dart

I've seen a bunch of code that is written like this in dart:

```
if (thisIsTrue) {
  // do something
   return;
}
```

What does this type of return, without a value, do exactly?

Comment: It returns no value ("void") from the function.  What happens when you test this?  Does it do anything unexpected?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-void function returns nothing dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60869984/non-void-function-returns-nothing-dart)

Comment: @David: subtle distinction.  In Dart, "void" is a "type", and "null" is a "value".  Here, the function returns the value "null".

Comment: @David I just wanted to know, for knowledge purposes. I've seen them a lot of times.

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff The StackOverflow answer explains a scenario, but in my case, I just want to know the use of return statements written that way.

Comment: @Henry It is used to stop a method early (since we are returning from it) in case something is true. It can be more easier to read than adding a big else statement which adds indentation to your code.

Answer (score 3):

Your code comes from a method which is specified to return `void` as its type and does therefore specify that whatever we are going to return, we must not use that value for anything.

While we must always return something in Dart, we can in `void` specified methods just do `return;` without anything and Dart will interpret this as `return null;`. Since the returned value is typed as `void` we does already signal to the caller of our method that it should not use the returned value so it does not matter that we return `null`.

The reason for this way of writing your code:

```
if (thisIsTrue) {
  // do something
   return;
}
```

Is because we want to use the fact that after a call of `return` we stop executing the rest of the method. So instead of having a big `else` statement (which can make it harder to read the code) we can just do a `if` with a `return;` if we want to make a check which determine if we need to execute the rest of the method.